# Creating a mock environment for an existing Java application

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking

I have this java application that I need to test.
The problem is the application was intedned to run in a certein environment. i.e a linux machine containing all kinds of files and scripts in specific locations (which the java application runs using Runtime class).

What I would like to do is make a mock classes for say the Runtime and System class.
But I do not want to add this code to the real application, nor have the application selecting in which mode to run at run-time.

I would rather make the application **compile** in this different mode... somthing similar to ifdef in C maybe.
I also thought about AspectJ as a possible solution...

Am I on the right track at all? am I missing something fundamental?

Thanks!

Comment: You don't need different compilation mode. Use mock with unit test and real classes in application. I don't think someone ships app with unit test classes. If you already using ant or maven just don't add unit test classes folder in package target/phase (automatic for maven)

Comment: It's probably best to define some service interfaces, e.g. `FileSystemService`. Then you can supply different implementations based on the context. Your default `FileSystemServer` implementation would call the real system methods, whereas you would mock the interface in your unit tests.

Comment: Yes, I understand that if the system was writing in a test-driven way it would be possible to provide a mock implementations.
However, what about a big system already poorly writing? Do I fix it to be test-oriented or can I have a quick solution with minimum changes to the application

Comment: Is preparing a 'mocked' runtime environment an option? What about creating empty files and scripts that do nothing in your test environment, would that do?

Comment: no... I do need a mocked runtime environment, but I need the scripts to return a specific output as the test needs.
This is why I thought of maybe "inject" a different "import" statemants at compile-time so that the mock class could be loaded instead of the real one

Comment: Ofri, are you aiming for automated testing or do you want to be able to run your app in a mocked environment?

Anyways, it looks like you are doing some end-to-end testing. I'd probably try writing some test harness that would prepare the mocked scripts with the answers specified in your test. I.e. in the test setup section I'd call a set of command that would create those scripts with expected (mocked) return values. Otherwise you may think of compiling test-only dependendencies into your test app - you could use maven to add them to classpath and override the original ones.